# React input required is not worked for me what ı have to do?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi ı am using react required normally works when i type input type=text required but problem is here, ı have a update function and its automatically fill inside when i clear input and submit required not works its accept empty.

value coming from the server

```
 <input type="input" className="form__field" placeholder="İsminiz" name="name" id="name" value={name}  onChange={e => this.setState({ name: e.target.value})}  required />
```

Comment: How exactly is the form submitted? Handling `onClick` of a button for instance won't check required fields first afaik, only a form's `onSubmit` will. This works for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-nightingale-098lx?file=/src/App.js

Comment: `required` only has an effect if you are using standard HTML forms, but if you are using react you probably have your own submit logic